# How can I prevent the same file being included twice when using hardlinks?

Tags: php, hyperlink, realpath, readlink

How can I prevent the same file being included twice? Here is my source code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 0);

if (!file_exists('ccc.php'))
    link('bbb.php', 'ccc.php');
if (!file_exists('ddd.php'))
    link('bbb.php', 'ddd.php');
require_once realpath('ccc.php');
require_once realpath('ddd.php');

$bbb = new Bbb();
echo $bbb->bb();
```

I receive:

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class Bbb, because the name is already in use in /path/to/ddd.php on line 2
```

It's not working with `realpath` because it just returns the path of the link, not the target. I've tried with `readlink` but unfortunately that only works for symlinks.

Comment: You can get the inode with ls-i and see if its already one you used?

Comment: @BugFinder would that not cause a performance issue? Surely, there must be a way to get the target of a link in `php` without using `exec`.

Comment: Well https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileinode.php seems to do the same....

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to reverse `fileinode`, so that I receive the target of the link but no luck.

Comment: I dont think you can. Hard links hide the visibility, soft links i recall have a counter..

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution. It's not ideal but for a quick fix it will do, until I am able to make sure the same files are never included twice:

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('html_errors', 0);

if (!file_exists('ccc.php'))
    link('bbb.php', 'ccc.php');
if (!file_exists('ddd.php'))
    link('bbb.php', 'ddd.php');

function includeFile($fileName)
{
    foreach (get_included_files() as $file)
    {
        if (fileinode($file) === fileinode($fileName))
            return null;
    }
    require_once $fileName;
}
includeFile('ccc.php');
includeFile('ddd.php');

$bbb = new Bbb();
echo $bbb->bb();
```

Thanks to [BugFinder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687262/bugfinder) for suggesting I use `fileinode`.